# Moving Button to the right

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML Page with a CSS. I want to align some buttons to the right. Even though in the normal HTML pages without this CSS template, the button would move to the right, it does not work anymore. Same is the case for similar buttons on the page. Align to the center does not work either.

This is what the page looks like:

[image]

```css
input.logout {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 80%;
  background: #3366cc;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #3366cc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input.logout:hover {
  color: #ffff;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<form align="right">
  <input class="logout" type="button" value="Logout" onclick="window.location.href='logout.php'" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Arun, there's not enough code provided. What's the css on `<form>` ? Is it a flex container or other ? There are multiple to align your `<button>` to the right depending on your code.

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: The code snippet you posted doesn't exhibit the behavior you describe. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Time to learn about `display: flex` and `display: grid`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add `float:right` to your button css

```css
input.logout {
width: 100px;
padding: 7px;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 80%;
background: #3366cc;
color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #3366cc;
border-radius: 10px;
float: right;
}
input.logout:hover {
color: #ffff;
background: #000;
border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<form align="right">
<input class="logout" type="button" value="Logout"onclick="window.location.href='logout.php'" />
</form>
```

Comment: You mean `float: right;` ? Don't forget to talk about clearing floats or that might make a mess later on.

Comment: Worked well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you are just going to have this `.logout` button on that line, you can just make it a block-level element with `display: block`, and add `margin-left: auto` so it is pushed to the right side; without using floats, since those can cause issues down the line.

```css
input.logout {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 80%;
  background: #3366cc;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #3366cc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
}

input.logout:hover {
  color: #ffff;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="logout" type="button" value="Logout" onclick="window.location.href='logout.php'" />
</form>
```

If you are going to have multiple buttons on the same line, maybe Flexbox would be the way to go instead:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

input.logout {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 80%;
  background: #3366cc;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #3366cc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

input.logout:hover {
  color: #ffff;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="flex">
  <input class="logout" type="button" value="Logout" onclick="window.location.href='logout.php'" />
  <input class="logout" type="button" value="Logout" onclick="window.location.href='logout.php'" />
  </div>
</form>
```